# Run multiple jquery function on one html input id

Tags: jquery, html

I have problem with Jquery functions on one input id
I want two Jquery function to execute on one ID,
Below are my codes

This is for setting input as TAG

```
$('#autocomplete').tagsInput({
        width: 'auto',
        'onAddTag': function () {
            //alert(1);
        },
```

This is for search with autocomplete,

```
    var countries = [
   { value: 'Andorra', data: 'AD' },
  // ...
  { value: 'Zimbabwe', data: 'ZZ' }
];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
lookup: countries,
delimiter : ';',
onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
}
});
```

Here is HTML code,

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="text" name="reply_cc" id="autocomplete" autocomplete="off"  class="form-control tags">
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Problem is, with this, only 1 functions of tagsInput is working,
It can not execute 2nd function of autocomplete to search my values,

How can i accomplish both function with one ID?

Thanks,

Comment: provide your html code

Comment: @vel, Added in my post

Answer (score 0):

You can bind multiple events like

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).bind({
  click: function() {
    // Do something on click
  },
  mouseenter: function() {
    // Do something on mouseenter
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

there isn't just one way of doing it.

But this is maybe the easiest to understand this:

```
<button id="awesome-button">Jo, Dude click me</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
    function awesomeOne () {
        console.log('first function');
    }

    function awesomeTwo () {
        console.log('second function');
    }

    $('#awesome-button').on('click', function() {
        awesomeOne();
        awesomeTwo();
    });
});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WebJedi/4Lz43nco/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using [jQuery-Tags-Input](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input). Which means you can include the autocomplete options as an extra parameter.

```
var countries = [
    { value: 'Andorra', data: 'AD' },
    // ...
    { value: 'Zimbabwe', data: 'ZZ' }
];

$('#autocomplete').tagsInput({
    width: 'auto',
    'onAddTag': function () {
            //alert(1);
    },

    autocomplete: {
        lookup: countries,
        delimiter : ';',
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```